# How to deploy workflow to openkm?

Tags: java, eclipse, workflow, jbpm, openkm

I have installed jbpm 6.3 and have a "hello world" workflow project to deploy to my openkm.
I can't find a "deployment tab" anywhere neither could i find an option to export .par file.

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just started working with Open KM recently.

You need to use the **JBPM Console**; log into the admin panel to upload the par workflow file.

The URL should look something similar to :-

**://{your-openkm-server}:8080/jbpm-console/admin/**

See screenshot below

[Sample jBPM Console Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhUrH.png)